# Issues with declaring enum

Tags: c++, c++11, enums, constructor

I'm getting an error when trying to declare an enum.  It says the identifier is undefined, but I am including the applicable file where it was defined.  (This is my first coding class so sorry in advance).  Where am I going wrong?  And how do I pass the enum to a constructor?

```
// in degree.h file

#ifndef Student_h
#define Student_h

#pragma once

enum class DegreeProgram { program1, program2, program3 };

#endif


// in student.h file

#ifndef Student_h
#define Student_h

#pragma once

#include "degree.h"

class Student {

private:
   DegreeProgram program;
};

#endif
```

Comment: its because you used the same header guards for both files, the first set prevents the code in the second set from being added (as it should) change the header guards in degree.h (which are still Student_h but shouldn't be)

Answer (score 2):

The **problem** is that you are using the same name `Student_h` in both of the include guards inside `degree.h` and `student.h`.

To solve this change the name of the include guards inside `degree.h` from `Student_h` to `DEGREE_H` as shown below:

**degree.h**

```
//------vvvvvvvv---->changed from Student_h to DEGREE_H
#ifndef DEGREE_H
#define DEGREE_H


enum class DegreeProgram { program1, program2, program3 };

#endif
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/ZC3LhAzYR)